# Soundcloud API + Python Desktop Application

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I have a question regarding writing Desktop applications in Python using the Soundcloud API. My problem is how can I implement a login functionality in my Desktop application without disclosing my client Secret. Because in order to get a login token I need to initialize the client with my client ID and secret. Is it possible somehow? Or do I have to use the Java or Objective-C API?

Or is it save to create Python bytecode and than publish my application? I haven't much experience with Python bytecode. Is it possible to extract variables or constants from the *.pyc file?